# Private Keys in my Bitcoin Wallet?

Tags: wallet, private-key

What are 'Private Keys'? and where do i find them in my wallet? How do I know it is a private key?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your wallet.

A Bitcoin private key is a 256bit (32bytes) random number (there is a max limit, but lets don't go into the details).
Often, wallets export them as a WIF encoded base58check string which looks like `L1esWYsDL8nBeTRmGjUiDru54nXS4wF811n3e7mbvoSjM2zZWJ6w`.

Sometimes, wallet use HD (look up BIP32 if you are interested).
Then the root private key starts with "xprv" and look like `xprv9s21ZrQH143K4bhMhuUKZnW9DW5Dx9mwGQseMNdoECsaCGdhL9N8jR6KG5c3UTYrKPTkRNEBfeX7LjE2VjScyLZYA3XqRpyYbhnZHnsUepS`

Search after "export private key" or "dump wallet", etc.

Comment: This is useful. Thank you! How does Bitcoin private key differ from Ethereum?  How do I save a private key to  USB? How do I know the difference between a private key and public key?

Comment: Bitcoin and Ethereum private keys are the same (Ethereum uses the same libsecp256k1 curve).

Comment: Save a private key to USB? You mean hardwarewallet? The whole idea of a hardware wallet is that you create the key on the device and the key will never leave the device.